# Hindi font is not getting displayed properly in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Can anyone help me to lead the Hindi font properly using the TCPDF library? I have successfully installed the font as .php and .z files have been generated but when I am running the code it's not displaying the text. Please check the screenshot for ref.

[image]

I tried everything by following TCPDF guidelines but nothing is working. I tried **mangal** and **freesans** families as well but those are translating the text in the wrong way.

Print Input: **नमस्ते आप कैसे**

Output : [image]

If anyone have any clue or solution then please answer to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the header `'Content-Type', 'application/pdf'` before outputting your pdf, like this:

```
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');
```

Not sure if it works with Hindi characters, but it does with spanish accented characters and letters not included in the english alphabet

Comment: I tried but not working, any other suggestions or lead tips?

Comment: I guess you can install and try some other fonts (see: https://hindi-fonts.com/). Also this video might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Swy8TuA5fZw